# Declaring variables in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm new to `Delphi` and I'm learning how to declare variables and looping.

If the var `Orden` values is 1 do something if its is 2 do something else. Here is what I'm trying but I don't know how to declare two values in "Orden"

What I'm triying to do here is to create a calculator "IgualClick" is the "equal" button where I'm triying to read what the "orden" (Order) is, if is 1 = add or 2 = subtract Thanks

Thanks..

```
procedure TForm1.IgualClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Orden : integer;
begin

  Orden := (1)(2);
  B := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
   Case orden of
     1 : Sumar;
     2 : Restar;

end;
```

Comment: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=DataTypes

Comment: http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/a/delphicourse.htm

Comment: Also F1, in Delphi IDE and Embarcadero's website

Comment: What are you trying to assign to the variable `Orden`? What do you think is the semantic meaning of `(1)(2)`?

Comment: Are you looking for an enumerated type? Or a sub range? You will really have to tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think he don't even know enumeration, set or else sintax in Delphi

Comment: @MatheusFreitas Which makes your answer a little premature.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't know if you know spanish but it's pretty clear he wants to do a basic calculator program, I'm just trying to help, like you

Comment: @MatheusFreitas Spanish isn't needed here. What's needed is clarification on what the meaning of `Orden := (1)(2)` is. Do you know?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understood your point and you are right, but as I know a little of spanish I guessed what he wanted and I've posted a solution to the problem I thought he had

Comment: Your edit does not help at all. Nobody here has any idea what you mean by `Orden := (1)(2)`. You will need to explain that.

Comment: Not to mention where do you define the `B` which is used in `B := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);`? Also, `StrToInt` based off an edit control is always a bad idea. Instead use `StrToIntDef(Edit1.Text, 1);` so it returns a default value if, let's say, someone types in `abc` into this edit control instead of `1` or `2`

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant to do this:

```
procedure TForm1.IgualClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Orden : integer;
begin          
  Orden := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  Case orden of
    1 : Sumar;
    2 : Restar;           
    else raise Exception.Create('Invalid Option!');
  end;
end;
```

And please read the language specification and documentation.

Please, if the answer is wrong make sure to Edit your question too. As I understood, when you click the Equals button, you retrieve the operand selected in the Edit1 and processes the operation (by calling Sumar, Restar methods)

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the trouble. What I'm triying to do here is to create a calculator

"IgualClick" is the "equal" button where I'm triying to read what the "orden" (Order) is, if is 1 = add or 2 = subtract

Thanks

Comment: The answer I've posted, reads the orden from Edit1, is that right?

Comment: What makes you think that `Orden`, the case variable, is contained in `Edit1`? The question doesn't indicate that. More likely `Edit1` contains an operand. Although, I'm guessing too.